# Kubuntu 17.04: sddm shows only black screen with the cursor

Tags: xorg, xserver, sddm

After xserver-core upgrade:

```
xserver-common:amd64 (2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1.1 -> 2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1.2)
xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1.1 -> 2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1.2)
xmir:amd64 (2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1.1 -> 2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1.2)
```

Also some plasma packages were updated to version `5.9.5-0ubuntu0.3`, but that shouldn't affect `sddm`.

`sddm` won't display login screen. Only black screen with x cursors is shown. I've tried moving `.kde`, `.config` and `.cache` folders from my `$HOME` without any success.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've downgraded `xorg` packages to previous versions:

```
  sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core=2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1
  sudo apt install xserver-common=2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1
```

After reboot login screen show up as expected.

I guess it's good idea to put packages on hold until the issue is resolved:

```
  sudo apt-mark hold xserver-xorg-core
  sudo apt-mark hold xserver-common
```